# jQuery Tablesorter - How do you disable filter by column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter, tablesort

I am trying to follow this example: 
ftp://ftp.jax.org/dgatti/ShortCourse2015/webapp/eqtl-viewer/src/static/js/jquery.tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html

however I am not able to disable the search widget for an individual column.

How do I disable the search widget (input) for a particular column in the table?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that link is to some site I've never heard of, and that's a really old version.

The most up-to-date documentation can be seen here: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html

If you look at the ["classes" tab](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html#classes) of the filter widget documentation, you'll see that adding a class name of `filter-false` to the header will disable the input filter for that column.

```
<th class="filter-false">Header</th>
```

If you want to hide the disabled filter, then add some additional css:

```
input.disabled { display: none; }
```